# Find a pattern with repetition of the last character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I tring to match all the words like 'ofekkk', 'goooo', 'carrrrr'
and then use the subsword befor the repetition, mean that I need 'ofe', 'g', 'car.
I tried

```
reg3 = re.compile(r'([a-z]+)([a-z])\2+')
reg3.findall('ofekkkk')

Out[90]: [('ofekk', 'k')]
```

but the first group - 'ofekk' it's not what I'm looking for

Thanks

Comment: `car` or `ca` for `carrrrr`?

Comment: it's not really matter because I know what is group 2

Comment: Try [`[x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(r'\b([a-z]*?)([a-z])\2+\b', 'ofekkk, goooo, carrrrr')]`](http://ideone.com/LdhSjy).

Comment: What are the real expected results? Maybe [`re.findall(r'\b([a-z]*?)([a-z])\2+\b', s)` will do](http://ideone.com/a8K1Q1)?

Comment: wow thanks ... the solution is using ? after +

Comment: So, that is the only thing you needed to change? Replacing the greedy quantifier with the lazy one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to replace the *greedy* quantifier with its *lazy* version:

```
reg3 = re.compile(r'([a-z]+?)([a-z])\2+')
                          ^^
```

If you need to allow cases where the first group can be empty, use `*?` instead of `+?`.

Since the `+?` / `*?` quantifiers ar lazy, the first capturing group will contain as few symbols as possible, the regex engine will skip the pattern and will try to match the `([a-z])` one with `\2+` first, and only upon no match the `([a-z]+?)` will "expand".

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries `\b`:

```
reg3 = re.compile(r'\b([a-z]*?)([a-z])\2+\b', re.I)
```

and filter the second group for each result:

```
res = [m[0] for m in reg3.findall(yourstring)]
```

Comment: It didn't help - the output is [('ofekkkkkk', 'k')] for reg3.findall('ofekkkkkk'

Comment: @OfekIsrael: no, it returns `['ofekkkk']`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem springs from using the maximally-*greedy* `+` operator. The `+` is consuming as much of the text as possible prior to allowing the remainder of your pattern to match.

Instead, try using the *reluctant* version, `+?`. This will only consume what has to be consumed in order to make the match:

```
import re

text = 'dog cow ofekkkk goooo carrrr'

#pat = r'\b([a-z]+?)([a-z])\2+'
pat = r'\b([a-z]+?)([a-z])\2*\b'
reg3 = re.compile(pat)

for m in reg3.finditer(text):
        print(m.group(0), m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Output is:

```
$ python test.py
dog do g
cow co w
ofekkkk ofe k
goooo g o
carrrr ca r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the greedy quantifier if you want to.

`\b(?:([a-z])(?!\1))+(?=([a-z])\2)`

Expanded

```
 \b    
 (?:
      ( [a-z] )                     # (1)
      (?! \1 )
 )+
 (?=
      ( [a-z] )                     # (2)
      \2 
 )
```

The greedy way would be some %30 quicker -

```
Regex1:   \b(?:([a-z])(?!\1))+(?=([a-z])\2)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    2.74 s,   2740.46 ms,   2740459 µs


Regex2:   ([a-z]+?)([a-z])\2+
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    3.64 s,   3639.44 ms,   3639438 µs
```